# Data not transferring between classes

Tags: android-studio, class, methods, singly-linked-list

I have three linked lists called "Titles" (String linked list), "Descriptions" (String linked list), and "Pictures" (Bitmap linked list). I'm 100% sure that they are full of data. I've printed out their data just before the line `MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, Titles, Descriptions, Pictures);` and it has exactly the data I expect ("MyAdapter" is a class). However, in the MyAdapter class, all three linked lists are null, as I get the following error:

```
2022-08-07 19:13:03.009 14983-14983/com.example.usshop E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.usshop, PID: 14983
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.LinkedList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.usshop.MyAdapter.<init>(MyAdapter.java:30)
        at com.example.usshop.Shop.CreateItems(Shop.java:70)
        at com.example.usshop.Shop$1.onDataChange(Shop.java:56)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Below is the code of the two classes (Note: for the "Shop" class, the "CreateItems" method mainly matters because it sends the data to the other class. Included the rest in case it somehow affects the issue):

```
public class Shop extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView rv;
    //Below is unimportant; ignore.
/*
    String s1[], s2[];
    int images[] = {R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.banana, R.drawable.graoe,
            R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.pineapple, R.drawable.peach};
 */

    LinkedList<String> Titles = new LinkedList<>(), Descriptions = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Integer> Prices = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Bitmap> Pictures = new LinkedList<>();

    DatabaseReference ItemsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop);

        //Whenever the value of ItemsReference changes, it is stored
        ItemsReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                // Storing all of the data
                for (DataSnapshot DS : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    BackendDataStorage TempData = DS.getValue(BackendDataStorage.class);

                    Titles.add(TempData.getTitle());
                    Descriptions.add(TempData.getDescription());
                    Prices.add(TempData.getPrice());
                    Pictures.add(Extras.StringToBitMap(TempData.getPicture()));
                }
                CreateItems();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.d("Error", "Failed to read value: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public void CreateItems () {
        Log.d("index", Titles.get(0)); // Just making sure Titles isn't null
        rv = findViewById(R.id.Recycler_View);

        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, Titles, Descriptions, Pictures);
        rv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private LinkedList<String> data1, data2;
    private LinkedList<Bitmap> images;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter (Context ct, LinkedList<String> s1, LinkedList<String> s2, LinkedList<Bitmap> img) {
        context = ct;

        // Looping through LinkedList indexes & replacing with new variables
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++) {
            data1.add(s1.get(i));
            data2.add(s2.get(i));
            images.add(img.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, in the `MyAdapter` class, all three linked lists are null

No, they are not. You have misread the error message. The error is not about any of the arguments you pass to the `MyAdapter` constructor, but about a member of the `MyAdapter` class.

Note for instance that there is no error on evaluating `s1.size()` in the `for` loop heading, so `s1` is not `null`.

But the error is not about `s1`, `s2` or `img`. It is about calling the `add` method on a `null` reference:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method `boolean java.util.LinkedList.add(java.lang.Object)` on a null object reference

The line where `add` is called, is here:

```
data1.add(s1.get(i));
```

So, `data1` is `null`. And this is indeed the case. Your class has a private instance member called `data1` which has not been initialised. You need to do something like:

```
data1 = new LinkedList<String>();
```